# how to get an url for a website which use ajax

Tags: ajax, url, frontend

For example, if I log in the gmail, I get an url. I click the next page, the view is different but the url is still the same. Can I get an url, when I click, which automatically show the second page of the gmail?

An url which load the ajax command